# Problem with python logging to another file/directory

Tags: python-3.x, logging, module

I'm trying to code an interface and I want to log to another file or on a file in another directory different things. I'm using logging module and for some reason it doesn't log anything at all

I tried reverting to `"filename = example.log"` a file that would be in the same directory as the program

**python**

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename= 'home/notcwd/example.log', 
                    format= '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s : %(message)s')

def example():
    logging.info('it works')
    return
```

I expect it to log to example.log 
but it doesn't log anything at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by default, only WARNING logs will be recorded.

If you can try `logging.warn()` instead `logging.info()`, you can see the entry in the log.

However, you can also modify the level by using `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`.

**Code:**

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    filename= 'home/notcwd/example.log', 
                    format= '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s : %(message)s')

def example():
    logging.info('it works')
    return

example()
```